# Add/Copy SPListItem object to Sharepoint List

Tags: splistitem, splist

explanation:

I have fetched list items based on conditions.
Like this.

```
var query = from SPListItem oItem in splist.Items
                                    where Convert.ToDateTime(oItem["Status"]).Equals("Completed")
                                    select oItem;


 foreach (SPListItem item in query)
 {
      // I get each SPListItem based on my condition
      // Now i want add/copy each list items to same list
 }
```

How do i add SPListItem whole object to same list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in query)
{
          SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
          foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
          {
                  if (!field.ReadOnlyField)
                        newItem[field.Id] = item[field.Id];                            
           }
           newItem.Update();
 }
```

Comment: i have tried. it give exception...
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

Comment: The error appears becoz... you need to add web.AllowUnSafeUpdates==true in the beginning.. then at the end make it as false

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
foreach(SPListItem item in splist.Items)
    {
      foreach(SPField field in splist.Fields)
        {
          SPListItem newItem=splist.Items.Add();
          newItem[field.ID]=item[field.ID];                       
          newItem.Update();
        }
     }
```

Comment: I fetched list items and want to copy list items to existing list.
and also many number of fields available in my fields.
so it's time consuming.

Comment: check the above now

Comment: i have tried. it give exception...
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.